# First and second order statistics

Tags: order-statistics

In this paper **[Boltzmann Machines](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~roweis/notes/boltz.pdf)**, the first paragraph of the second section **2. Boltzmann Machines** argues that,

> we could never train such a network with three units to visit the
>   states *(0,0,0)*, *(0,1,1)*, *(1,0,1)* and *(1,1,0)* with some probabilities,
>   but not the other four possible states. This is because **the first and
>   second order statistics** (the **mean** of each component and **correlations**
>   between components) are the same for these four states as the
>   remaining four and so the network can not discriminate them.

As I learned from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrderStatistic.html), order logic is just to order the attributes of the samples and take the i-th element of it.

I am wondering why the first and second order statistics of the two sets are the same.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the surface, it seems like the point they're trying to make has more to do with identifiability than order statistics.
**Perhaps, in their language, "order statistics" refers to [moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)) (in statistics)** or powers of a sample.  This is evidenced by their statement in parentheses about the mean and covariance.

If they are actually referring to moments, and a finite set of moments drive the states in question (e.g. as a normal distribution is fully determined by its mean and [co]variance), then they might simply be describing the model's inherent symmetry and/or limitations by way of its low-order moments.

Also, it sounds like they're voicing concerns similar to those that arise when [considering the identifiability of mixture models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model#Identifiability).

Comment: I think you are right. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 13):

I know that this is an old question with an accepted answer. But in the hope of helping someone finding this question now or in the future I'm answering.

I believe the paper was referring to "low-order statistics" and not "order statistics". Low-order statistics are functions or quantitative measures which use the zeroth, first and second power of a sample.

For a probability density, the first-order statistic (first [moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics))) is the [mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean), the second-order statistic (second moment) is the [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance).

Comment: I agree, they even mention it as such. I came here to clear the concept up that I have seen in another paper "Covariance Pooling for Facial Recognition" which most certainly refers to Low-order statistics and not $i$-th order as they are defined in OP's link